# why text is not matching in angular using toEqual?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test my component using `jasmine` but I am not sure why i `fail`

here is y code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bup8gb
[image]

```
describe('initial display',()=>{
   it('show counter text',()=>{
      debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p.abc'));
      el = fixture.nativeElement;
       fixture.detectChanges();
     expect(el.textContent).toEqual('counter 1')
   })
 })
```

Comment: You may want to trim the text content before using it for comparaisons: `el.textContent.trim()`

Comment: but I want it should show `counter 1` only

Comment: `textContent` may have some additional leading or trailing spaces that make the comparaison fail. Trimming it will make sure they're gone. (**`'  counter 1' !== 'counter 1'`**)

Comment: why it is showing `INCREMENT` `text`

Comment: i think there is issue `      debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p.abc'));
` in this line

Comment: Last time I was using `By` I had troubled on nested css. `By.css('abc')` might do that trick.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't it be `expect(debugEl.textContent).toEqual('counter 1')` (`debugEl` instead of `el`)? Because `el` is your `div` including the button `"INCREMENT"` whilst `debugEl` is the `p` where the count is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper syntax to do what you need:

```
describe('initial display',()=>{
  it('show counter text',()=>{
    debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.abc'));
    el = debugEl.nativeElement; //** You need to get the element from the degubEl
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toEqual('counter 1')
  })
})
```

Here is another way to do it, but it may not be desirable if you have more than one `p` element in the template:

```
describe('initial display',()=>{
  it('show counter text',()=>{
    el = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.querySelector('p').textContent).toEqual('counter 1')
  })
})
```

Comment: could you please look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823470/jest-mock-is-not-a-function-in-react-error/49825355#49825355